# How do I display url for seo frendly?

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I want to change my website url display from bdnow.net/sites/businessName/index.php?page=pageName to bdnow.net/sites/businessName/pageName

if i write

```
RewriteEngine On
1 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
2 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
3 RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /index.php?name=$1 [L]
```

it will go back to bdnow.net/index.php not index.php of businessName directory
Please help

Comment: Take a look into the documentation of the tool you use. That is where you will find answers. Either use the `RewriteBase` command or simply `/businessName/index.php`.

Comment: Oh, and besides: `RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /index.php?name=$1 [L]` does _not_ work in a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess") but only in the real http server configuration files. `RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /index.php?name=$1 [L]` would work...

Comment: Thank you arkascha for your response, however it will access back to root index.php file not sub directory index.php file

Comment: I had tried this but still not working: 'RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z]*)$/(.*)$ http://bdnow.net/sites/$1/index.php?page=$2'

Answer (score 0):

If this does not work then you have some additional rewriting rules in place which you did not mention. This sometimes is the case within the application logic creating absolute references.

If you need to start debugging then take a look at "rewrite logging". It is documented, obviously, and allows to get a closer look at what is actually going on inside the rewriting engine on a step by step manner.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)/?$ /sites/businessName/index.php?name=$1 [END]
```

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This implementation will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).